# How to use jq try with multiple conditions like a case?

Tags: switch-statement, jq

I need to output in a single column the value of a field A if it's not null or the value of field B if not null or nothing if both A and B are null.

When I just had filed A to test I wrote this which worked ok

```
try .fieldA catch ""
```

But now as I need to take field B if A is null I tried those, and nothing worked

```
try .fieldA catch try .fieldB catch "" => this only returned empty values ever
try (.fieldA or .fieldB) catch ""  => this one outputs true or false, 2 resultst instead of 1
try (.fieldA,.fieldB) catch ""  => this one outputs both A and B if both are not nulll, so 2 resultst instead of 1
```

I'd like the try to stop evaluating whenever the first result is not null

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [alternate operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) `//`, which takes the second alternative if the first is `null` or `false`, and `empty` for the "nothing" result.
If accessing any field might fail, additionally use the [optional operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression/OptionalOperator:?) `?` on those fields.

```json
{
  "fieldA": "A1 present",
  "fieldB": "B1 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldB": "B2 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldA": "A3 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
```

```sh
jq '.fieldA // .fieldB // empty'
```

```json
"A1 present"
"B2 present"
"A3 present"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CcoFjEgwIy)

---

Addressing @peak's "warning": If you want to capture a filed that has the explicit boolean value `false`, while not capturing it if it is either missing or explicitly set to `null`, you can use `values` which selects non-null values only, and `first` to retrieve the first one that exists among a given stream of alternatives:

```json
{
  "fieldA": "A1 present",
  "fieldB": "B1 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldA": false,
  "fieldB": "B2 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldA": null,
  "fieldB": "B3 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldB": "B4 present",
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
{
  "fieldC": "irrelevant"
}
```

```sh
jq 'first(.fieldA, .fieldB | values)'
```

```json
"A1 present"
false
"B3 present"
"B4 present"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7gWkk8GvuO)

Using this approach, there's no need to provide the explicit `empty` case. However, if you want to have a default fallback, add it as the last item in the stream, e.g. `first(.fieldA, .fieldB, "" | values)`.

Comment: How to use ? if accessing fails ?

Comment: @glitchtracker Try `jq '.fieldA? // .fieldB? // empty'`. I updated my response with links to the relevant sections in the jq manual.

Comment: Actually, "" may be better than empty, because it translate to a blank column suing tsv, whereas empty does not produces the column, which can cause problem if we output as a tsv. Thanks again for your quick help

Comment: WARNING: the proposed solution does not distinguish `false` from `null`.  Using the example, consider for example if .fieldA is `false`.

Comment: @peak Even though I stated in the beginning that `false` and `null` are treated equally, I have now added an alternative to distinguish the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

jq's `//` operator has quite complicated semantics (*)
and in particular, when evaluating `E // F`, no distinction is made between E being `null`, `false`, or the empty stream.

Also, given an object as input, the expression `.x` will evaluate to the JSON value `null` if the key "x" is explicitly
specified as `null` **or** if the key "x" is not present at all.

Thus, *assuming an object has been given as input*,
if we want .fieldA if .fieldA is non-null,
and otherwise .fieldB if .fieldB is non-null,
and otherwise the string "missing", then we would have to write something along the lines of:

```
  if   .fieldA != null then .fieldA
  elif .fieldB != null then .fieldB
  else "missing"
  end
```

Simply replace "missing" by `empty` to achieve the objective stated in the original question.

---

(*) See the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#or-versus-)
for complete details.